# C# passing data between two open windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, variables, button, textbox

I an looking for a way to pass the content of a TextBox or a variable between two open windows in WPF. I can't show any code because I haven't started writing it yet but it should happen with a button click.

Comment: Please edit your Question and add more information to it. What data do you want to pass? How would you like to pass it and where do you want to call it? (The button press)

Comment: Start writing it and then post relevant code when you have issues.  You're basically saying "write my code"

Comment: Are these two windows in the same process? Or in different processes?

Answer (score 0):

In order for two windows / classes to communicate, they need to have a reference to each other.
While I am not too familiar with xaml or WPF development, in a Windows Form application you could do this via modifying the constructor for each form class and have it accept an optional argument of type Form

Eg:

```
MyForm1(Form optionalForm = null){

if(optionalForm != null){
      formWeNeedToUse = optionalForm;
      }
}
private Form formWeNeedToUse {get;set;}
```

If you have the fields set to public, you can also directly set the variables outside of constructors.

In Windows Forms - you can also use Application.OpenForms[0] to get the first open form, and ...OpenForms[1] to get the second.
I am unsure if this exists in Wpf though.